# How can I run multiple codeception suites (but not all) in one command?

Tags: codeception

In the [PHP Codeception test framework](http://codeception.com/), I want to be able to run multiple suites at once.

I can run them all like this:

```
codecept run
```

Or I can run individual suites like this:

```
codecept run acceptance
codecept run unit
codecept run browser
```

But I want to be able to run just two at a time, like this

```
codecept run acceptance,unit // This is not a thing. How can I do this?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Feb. 2017 it is possible to run multiple suites using the comma syntax. Per the [Codeception docs](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Commands#Run):

```
codecept run unit,functional: run only unit and functional suites
```

Answer (score 6):

One way you can get this result is by skipping the suites you don't want to run.

```
codecept run --skip unit --skip acceptance
```